# Custom validation for confirmPassword using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to build an register in my angular/ionic app. In my register there are 6 fields in a formGroup (username, firstname, lastname, password, confirmPassword, sex). Before i send the data to my server i want to validate it on the client with anuglar validations. Every validation works with except confirmPassword. I did several tutorials and read several articles but none of them code solve my problem.

Hope, one of you could help me..

```
this.formRegister = formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.pattern('^(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$')]), UsernameValidator.checkUsername ],
      firstname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')])],
      lastname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')])],
      rPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$')])],
      cPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required]), (control => PasswordValidator.confirmPassword(control, this.formRegister, 'rPassword'))],
      sex: ['']
},
{
      updateOn: "blur"
})
```

as you can see, i want that the validation fires if the field loses focus

my current customPasswordValidation:

```
static confirmPassword(control: FormControl, group: FormGroup, matchPassword: string) {
    
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        
        if (!control.value || group.controls[matchPassword].value !== null || group.controls[matchPassword].value === control.value) {
            resolve(null)
        }
        
        resolve({ 'mismatch': true })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.. i had used an 'or' instead of an 'and'

If you have the same problem, you can build your custom validation like this:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class PasswordValidator {

    static confirmPassword(control: FormControl, group: FormGroup, matchPassword: string) {
        
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            
            if (!control.value && group.controls[matchPassword].value !== null || group.controls[matchPassword].value === control.value) {
                group.controls['cPassword'].setErrors(null)
                resolve(null)
            } else {
                group.controls['cPassword'].setErrors({ 'mustMatch': true })
                if (matchPassword == 'rPassword') {
                    resolve({ 'mustMatch': true })
                } else {
                    resolve(null)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

With this validation it will be checked if the passwords match if you change your password or the confirmPassword field.
Don't forget to call your validation on your password field and confirmPassword field like this

```
rPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$')]), (control => PasswordValidator.confirmPassword(control, this.formRegister, 'cPassword'))],
cPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required]), (control => PasswordValidator.confirmPassword(control, this.formRegister, 'rPassword'))],
```

On your html-file you can read out your errors like this:

```
<div *ngIf="formRegister.controls.cPassword.errors?.mustMatch && formRegister.controls.cPassword.dirty">
    Passwords must match!
</div>
```

In this case the error will be shown, if you have focused the field once and a validation fires